# Mssql subquery inside a substring

Tags: sql-server, subquery, substring

I need to remove the last character of my subquery but I cannot figure out how to reference my subquery in the subselect as I need the length of it.

The subselect collects all rows and converts them into a single string by appending them with a separator ";".

This is what I need: (see code below "LENGTH" needs to get the string of the sub select)

```
(SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT 
                    d1.name +'; '
    FROM   
                    data1 d1 
                    inner join data2 d2
                    on d1.id = d2.id
    WHERE   
                    d1.id = dOfOutterSelect.id 
    ORDER BY
                    d1.CreatedOn FOR XML PATH('') 

    ),
LENGTH(),1)) 

As "Row name",
```

Comment: If that is what you need.. what's your question? :)

Comment: `for xml path` is a mssql server syntax, you tagged mysql, please clarify.

Comment: This isn't mysql

Comment: Move the subquery to FROM clause.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this stuff, of course i meant mssql. I corrected the post and added the following description:
This is what I need: (see code below "LENGTH" needs to get the string of the subquery)

Answer (score 0):

One fix that is frequently applied to the problem of the extra separator character with the `for xml` clause, is to use the `STUFF()` function instead of the `SUBSTRING()` function.

**Sample data**

```
create table data1
(
  id int,
  name nvarchar(10),
  createdOn date
);

insert into data1 (id, name, createdOn) values
(1, 'Andrew', '2020-05-01'),
(2, 'Bella',  '2020-03-01'),
(3, 'Cedric', '2020-12-01');

select * from data1;
```

**Current approach**

Add separator `;`  *after* each `name`.

```
select
(
  select d1.name + '; '
  from data1 d1
  order by d1.createdOn
  for xml path ('')
) as ColumnName;
```

Result:

```
ColumnName
-----------------------
Bella; Andrew; Cedric;
```

Problem: the result has a *trailing* separator `;` . Removing it with the `SUBSTRING()` function requires to know the string length.

**Suggested approach**

Add separator `;`  *before* each `name`.

```
select
(
  select '; ' + d1.name
  from data1 d1
  order by d1.createdOn
  for xml path ('')
) as ColumnName;
```

Result:

```
ColumnName
-----------------------
; Bella; Andrew; Cedric
```

New problem: the result has a *leading* separator `;` . Removing it can be done with the `STUFF()` function because its position (at the start) and length (fixed separator) are known.

**Solution**

Adding the `STUFF()` function ([function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql)) to the suggested approach.

```
select stuff(              -- add stuff() function
(
  select '; ' + d1.name
  from data1 d1
  order by d1.createdOn
  for xml path ('')
)
, 1, 2, '') as ColumnName; -- start at position 1, for length of 2, replace with empty
```

Result:

```
ColumnName
---------------------
Bella; Andrew; Cedric
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=042d07fdc40d1f859e79a23186582464) to see everything in action.